# Finding later added data from two layers in QGIS or ArcMap?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers

I have two layers which consist of 2010 and 2011 years POI. And in QGIS I want to find which POI have been added new in 2011 data.

Or can we get result from ArcGis or any other tool?

Comment: absolutely, just start marking your questions as answered and you will probably get a response

Comment: what is the problem? dont u like my question or you dont understand?

Comment: This site requires give and take.  So far you are just taking.  Go and review the answers to your other questions and start marking them as accepted and then people might help.

Comment: sorry for my fault. i will improve my que. thks for your advice...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a "select by location" to find all of the newly added features?  Use your 2010 POI points, select all features from the 2011 POI points that intersect (or are an exact match) to find the similar features in the 2011 dataset, then "switch selection" on your 2011 dataset.  This should give you all features that were added after the 2010 dataset was released.

You might also want to find all of the POI that have been removed since 2010.  To do this, simply reverse the layers and run the same procedure, selecting features from 2010 that do not match 2011 POI's.